# Can't install PPA after switching to Ubuntu

Tags: ppa

I installed 13.10 on a partition that had Mint on it. When trying to add any ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snwh/moka-gtk-theme-daily
```

I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: /usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py: not found
```

How can I point it to the right file?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I just found out that adding new PPAs via the software and updates tool works. Not a perfect solution, but it works.

Comment: Are you running linux mint?

Comment: If you are not running Mint you need to re-install and not upgrade to Ubuntu if you want to switch to Ubuntu.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu with the option to delete the existing Mint installation.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the ppa. As @Rinzwind says, you appear to have problems from not reformatting the partition when switching.

Comment: You should really do a clean install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be that this PPA is tailored towards Mint and can't be installed to Ubuntu. Try other PPAs.

If they all fail, bad luck. You messed up Ubuntu installation. You have leftover Mint files in your Ubuntu partition. It can't be repaired because nobody know what exactly was left. 
Reinstall your Ubuntu, don't forget to either format root partitions or remove all folders that are not cleanly your own from it.

Comment: I solved this by deleting /usr/local/bin/add-apt-repository and /usr/local/bin/apt-add-repository, (script/symlink left over by mint), then `sudo apt-get --purge remove python-software-properties software-properties-common`, then re-installing them.  I really didn't feel like doing a clean install, and haven't had any issues except a few with apt, all which were resolvable without much hassle.